# Elasticsearch aggregators - How missing values work

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of users who have a field availability. Below is the data mapping of the field

```
"mappings": {
 "users": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "_all": {
       "enabled": false
    },
   "properties": {
        "availability": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
              "null_value": "_unspecified_"
         }, ...
```

In this field user can either have a limited set of values which are lets say `value1`, `value2` and `value3` or it can be empty.

I do a simple terms aggregation on it

```
{
 "aggs" : {
   "availability" : {
      "terms" : { 
         "field" : "availability",
         "min_doc_count": 0,
         "missing": "Unspecified"                
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I get in output

```
{
"aggregations": {
  "availability_location": {
    "value1": 23, 
    "value2": 143, 
    "value3": 636, 
    "Unspecified": 127, 
    "_unspecified_": 490
 }
```

My question is why are count in Unspecified and **unspecified** different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unspecified` in filters gives count of users who dont have this field in data. And `__unspecified__` gives count of users who have the field but it has `null` value.